# SO question page opens with tag edition input focused

Tags: bug, user-interface, new-nav

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript%20java%20arrays%20performance%20linux%20postgresql%20sql%20html%20css%20algorithm%20go%20jquery%20regex%20promise?mode=any) opens with the tag edition input focused which is very inconvenient when you use a shortcut to refresh the list.

Worse: Every time I focus the browser tab, the input is also focused.

[image]